# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que un TimeOut me detenga un script en Python, si no reconocerlo para saltar lo que genera ese TimeOut o reintetarlo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo un programa de Python3 y estoy utilizando Selenium y Pandas para acceder a una página, extraer unos datos en repetidas ocaciones y por último crear un excel que guardé todos los datos que anteriormente extrajo de la página Web.
Mi problema es que a veces por cuestiones de conexión o la página misma tarda más tiempo del que le asigne al programa en conectar con la Web o directamente no lo hace, frenando esto todo el código y haciendome perder los datos anteriormente guardados.
Me gustaría saber si existe una forma de identificar estos TimeOut que hacen que el código se detenga, para que no frene el código, si no que vuelva a intentar ejecutarlo o en su defecto pase al siguiente dato que debe buscar.

En resúmen quiero saber si existe una manera de reconocer estos errores de tiempo o de coneción y que en vez de cerrarme el código, frene ese proceso y continue con el siguiente.

Comment: Podrías mostrar cómo tienes la parte de la espera `WebDriverWait` y/o `wait.until(...)`, si es que las tienes así, a ver si se puede mejorar. A lo mejor esa parte se pueda meter en un `try/except` para evitar el cierre abrupto del script si falla la conexión.

Comment: Que has intentado?, pon un ejemplo minimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, 
aqui las preguntas que no muestran algun intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, 
edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el 
(Recorrido de bienvenida)[https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio 
y en (Cómo Preguntar)[https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask].